# При нажатии на кнопку переходит по ссылке

Tags: html, css

Дело в том, что кнопка "**далее**" (осуществляется переход на другую страничку) и ссылка "**забыли пароль?**" (тоже переход на другую страничку) находятся друг под другом.

Возникает конфликт: то есть если нажать на кнопку "далее" ниже середины, то переход будет по ссылке.

```css
html {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
body{
    background-image: url("img.png");
}
.form{
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    width: 20%;
    min-width:300px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    padding: 1% 3% 3% 3%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-radius: 5%;
    border: 1% solid rgb(189, 189, 189);
    box-shadow:
        0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109,  0.7), 
        0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset; 
    
    text-align: center;
}
h1{
    padding-top: 0;
    /*margin-top: 0;*/
    color:rgb(6, 6, 41);
}
.link{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top:10%;
    color:  #666;
    /*font-weight: 0;*/
}
input[type="email"], input[type="password"], input[type="text"]{
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow:
        0pt 2px 5px rgba(105, 108, 109,  0.7), 
        0px 0px 8px 5px rgba(208, 223, 226, 0.4) inset; 
    padding: 10px;
    margin:2px;
}
.sub_style{
    width: 87%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color:rgb(35, 35, 48);
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid rgb(35, 35, 48);
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_reg.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <h1>Вход</h1>
        <form action="/" id="form">
            <p><input type="email"  name="email" required placeholder="Введите email" value=""></p>
          <p><input type="password"  name="passwd" required placeholder="Введите пароль" value=""></p>
          <p><input type="submit" class="sub_style" name="sub" value="далее"></p>
        </form>
        <a class="link" href=forgot_password.html>Забыли пароль?</a>
      </div>
    <script src="./auth.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
Код по ссылке: `https://codepen.io/shtykovaaa/pen/OJRzLJK`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте это

```
.link {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

У "Далее" уже есть margin-bottom, который смещает "Забыли пароль".

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @АннаШтыкова, если вам помог ответ, то, пожалуйста, отметьте его как решение, нажав галочку рядом с ним